# Docker Volume invalid reference format

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I want to use docker volume so that I can mount two different folders in a container.
I am using multiple docker volume statements in a single command but it is not woking. I am getting "invalid reference format"

I am trying this command-

sudo docker run -d -p 10010:8080 -v /Desktop/Jbilling/digilab4u-billing/jbillings/bin/hsql:/opt/jbilling-community-4.1.1/bin/hsql -v /Desktop/Jbilling/digilab4u-billing/jbilling:opt/jbilling-community-4.1.1/jbilling jbilling-community-4.1.1

Could anyone help me out with this

Thanks

Comment: try double quoting your volumes and there is no registry address in your image i guess its already there on your system , try with quotes like this 

sudo docker run -d -p 10010:8080 -v "/Desktop/Jbilling/digilab4u-billing/jbillings/bin/hsql:/opt/jbilling-community-4.1.1/bin/hsql" -v "/Desktop/Jbilling/digilab4u-billing/jbilling:opt/jbilling-community-4.1.1/jbilling" jbilling-community-4.1.1

Answer (score 1):

You are not using image_name

```
sudo docker run -d -p 10010:8080 -v /Desktop/Jbilling/digilab4u-billing/jbillings/bin/hsql:/opt/jbilling-community-4.1.1/bin/hsql -v /Desktop/Jbilling/digilab4u-billing/jbilling:opt/jbilling-community-4.1.1/jbilling jbilling-community-4.1.1 IMAGE_NAME
```

Comment: I am using the image name also, you can see jbilling-community-4.1.1 is an image

Comment: try double quoting your volumes and there is no registry address in your image i guess its already there on your system , try with quotes like this sudo docker run -d -p 10010:8080 -v "/Desktop/Jbilling/digilab4u-billing/jbillings/bin/hsql:/opt/jbilling-community-4.1.1/bin/hsql" -v "/Desktop/Jbilling/digilab4u-billing/jbilling:opt/jbilling-community-4.1.1/jbilling" jbilling-community-4.1.1